# Windows FTP batch file returns "200 type set to A" on mget command

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I am trying to automate a FTP job using a Windows batch file. When the `mget *.zip` line in the FTP batch file is executed this message is displayed:

> 200 type set to A

and no files are transferred. How can I resolve this?

[image: Output after execution of mget *.zip]

The file was working previously before I changed something.

The batch file command is

```
ftp -n -i -s:FtpCommands.txt not.a.real.ftphost
```

The commands in the `FtpCommand.txt` file are

```
USER UserName
Password
cd /FtpFolder
lcd C:\WorkstationFolder
ascii
mget *.zip
```

After doing a `ls` I get the below output

[image: LS output]

Comment: Issue an `ls`  command and show us an output.

Comment: updated original question with the output of the ls command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to download `.zip` files from a directory, where there are no `.zip` files. So, nothing is downloaded.

Maybe you wanted to download the `.gz` files:

```
mget *.gz
```

Answer (score -1):

USER UserName Password cd /FtpFolder lcd C:\WorkstationFolder ascii mget *.zip

try to put a 'ENTER' between command, eg:

```
USER UserName Password 
cd /FtpFolder 
lcd C:\WorkstationFolder
ascii
mget *.zip
```

Comment: 1) there's a new line (enter) already 2) were it not, you would not be authenticated and all commands would be failing accordingly.